# mySQL 8.0 - Trying to develop a query to measure duration at a specific value

Tags: mysql, state, duration

I have the following table with millions of records

```
+----------------------+-----------+------------+
| trnWhen              | Alias     | Value      |
+----------------------+-----------+------------+
| 2022-12-01 00:03:00  | DevID1    |  0         |
| 2022-12-01 00:04:00  | DevID2    |  1         |
| 2022-12-01 01:00:00  | DevID2    |  1         |
| 2022-12-01 01:25:00  | DevID1    |  1         |
| 2022-12-01 02:00:00  | DevID1    |  1         |
| 2022-12-01 02:00:00  | DevID2    |  1         |
| 2022-12-01 02:25:00  | DevID1    |  0         |
| 2022-12-01 02:45:00  | DevID2    |  0         |
| 2022-12-01 03:00:00  | DevID1    |  0         |
| 2022-12-01 03:00:00  | DevID2    |  0         |
| 2022-12-01 03:30:00  | DevID1    |  1         |
| 2022-12-01 04:00:00  | DevID2    |  1         |
| 2022-12-01 04:10:00  | DevID1    |  0         |
+----------------------+-----------+------------+
```

What I want as a result is total hours where Value = 1 per Alias between a set of dates (Like 2022-12-01 00:00:00 to 2022-12-02 00:00:00).  Usually I would look at this on a daily basis, but don't want to restrict the query to that.  Expected Result like:

```
Alias      RunHours
DevID1      1.33
DevID2     22.75
```

If there is not a preceding '0' then the value is assumed to be 1 at the start time.  (Like in the case of DevID2).
If there is not a post '0' then the value is assumed to be 1 at the end time. (Like in the case of DevID2)

Ultimately what I want is the number of times it changes Value to 1 as well.  Such as:

```
Alias      Runhours     Starts
DevID1      1.33          2
DevID2     22.75          1
```

I have figured out the Starts for a single Alias with the following:

```
Set @AL = DevID1;

SELECT Alias, COUNT(*) as Starts
FROM history curr
WHERE Alias = @AL 
AND curr.value = 1

and trnwhen Between '2022-12-01 00:00:00' and '2022-12-05 00:00:00'
AND (
    SELECT value
    FROM history prev
    WHERE Alias = @AL  
    AND prev.trnWhen < curr.trnwhen
        
    ORDER BY trnwhen DESC
    LIMIT 1
) = 0;
```

But I am stuck at getting this any further

Comment: are there duplicate trnWhen values for a given Alias?  if so, does the table have a primary key?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  with mysql 8 you would use lag for this, in a subquery

Comment: Yes.  Thousands of trnWhen values for a given Alias.

Comment: mySQL Version 8.0.13

Comment: is there ever the *same* trnWhen value for the same Alias?  if so, what determines the order?

Comment: No.  There is never a same trnWhen for the same alias

Answer (score 1):

If `trnwhen` is the timestamp indicates the start of an event (`alias`, `value`) and the situation continues until next event, then:

1. Use `lead()` to calculate the (start, end) of each event and its duration
2. Use `lag()` to get previous `value` and compare with current `value` to get `starts` (0 -> 1)

```sql
with cte as (
select alias,
       coalesce(timestampdiff(minute, trnwhen, lead(trnwhen,1) over (partition by alias order by trnwhen)),0) as minutes,
       value,
       case when coalesce(lag(value, 1) over (partition by alias order by trnwhen),1) = 0 and value = 1 then 1 else 0 end as starts
  from history)
select alias,
       sum(case when value=1 then minutes else 0 end)/60.0 as runhours,
       sum(starts) as starts
  from cte
 group by alias
 order by alias;
```

Comment: This produces EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Thank you very much!

Comment: given they want an implicit beginning value of 1, I think you want to use lag, not lead